# Prevent getElementById from executing prematurely?

Tags: javascript

I have an init() function that runs when document.readyState=="complete" so that any getElementById call is valid. Now I am dynamically loading a second javascript file. How do I insure any getElementById calls in the second javascript file do not execute before the element loads?

Comment: Have the first script call the second script's entry point when the first script is done.

Comment: This sounds like you're on step 3 or 4 of a series of workarounds to an underlying problem that could probably be solved in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your script declaration comes after the HTML then it's all good... otherwise you might be able to use `window` `onload` event

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
   var node = document.getElementById('myNode');
});
```

Comment: Effectively that's what I have in the 1st script: 

    document.onreadystatechange=InitJS;
    function InitJS(){
       if (document.readyState=="complete"){
        // getElementById  goes here so it doesn't execute before the element has loaded.
       }

Is there any reason I can't create another listener for onreadystatechange in the second script?   Could it be that simple?

Charlie might be right. I had already begun thinking I need to simplify.

Comment: Nope, not that simple. I ran an experiment and the second script's  document.onreadystatechange listener seems to bump the first.

Comment: How are you adding the listener, can you post an example? The best way would be using `addEventListener`, that way you won't be overriding any calls

Comment: I was wrong.  It does work. I went back to see if I could use another event, and realized  window.addEventListener("load" ...  IS another event, and I can add as many listeners as needed.

Comment: addEventListener works so much cleaner than document.onreadystatechange / document.readyState==="complete" Is there any reason for me not to drop the latter approach entirely?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between `document ready` and `window load` is that `window load` event will wait as well for images whereas document ready will just wait for the DOM to load, excluding images... so actually maybe better to use `document ready`... I think the problem here is more in the implementation details... instead of assigning a function to the event like `document.onDOMContentLoaded = function()...` you will use addEventListener like  so `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { ...`
In the latter way you can add as many event listeners as you like whereas the former way you can only have one and will subsequently override them if reassigned. Hope that made it a little clearer

Comment: Thank you (again). I missed the difference between adding the listener, and assigning the function directly. My testing had already led me in that direction, but your explanation helped put the finishing touches on it.